# VBScript and refreshing an IFrame with a file exist Check

Tags: html, vbscript

I am trying to refresh my iframe every 30 sec and have it swtich to an error page if the page is unavaiable. I get a "Cannot use parentheses when calling a Sub" error and the vbscript never works. I have looked at several examples of others trying to do similar things, and i cannot tell what i am doing wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Census Status</title>
      </head>  
      <body>
        <iframe class="main" id="main" src="G:\CensusAlert\Default.html" width="96%" height="95%"></iframe>    
        <script type="text/vbscript">
        Function refreshGadget
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            Set iFrame = document.getElementById("main")
            If objFSO.FileExists("G:\CensusAlert\Default.html") then
                iFrame.src = "G:\CensusAlert\Default.html"
            Else
                iFrame.src = "C:\Program Files\SAMCAlert\Error.html"
            End If
        End Function
        window.setInterval(refreshGadget, 30000, VBScript)
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Have a look at Eric Lippert's [most awesome article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/15/52996.aspx) on that matter before you remove the parentheses around the argument list of `window.setInterval`.

Comment: That article was exactly what i needed thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Census Status</title>
      </head>  
      <body>
        <iframe class="main" id="main" src="G:\CensusAlert\Default.html" width="96%" height="95%"></iframe>    
        <script type="text/vbscript">
        Function refreshGadget
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            Set iFrame = document.getElementById("main")
            If objFSO.FileExists("G:\CensusAlert\Default.html") then
                iFrame.src = "G:\CensusAlert\Default.html"
            Else
                iFrame.src = "C:\Program Files\SAMCAlert\Error.html"
            End If
        End Function
        window.setInterval("refreshGadget", 30000, "VBScript")
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Fixed it thanks Ansgar Wiechers

Comment: Is it really fixed? Because to me it seem it only should work if you use `window.setInterval "refreshGadget", 30000, "VBScript"`

Comment: Yes, I tried that first and it failed completely but after adding the quotation marks it accepted the command. The article you gave me did not outline that, but it put me on the right track to figuring it out.

Comment: Oh, I can explain the double quotes, `SetInterval` needs a functionname (or just a statement) as a string. Just as you would use `Execute`, `Eval` or (more sophisticated) `GetRef`. What I was wondering was if it worked with the parenthesis in place, because Subs and Functions cannot be called with parenthesis if there is no `Call` or assignment in front of the sub. ([What do you mean "you cannot use parenthesis"?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/15/52996.aspx))