# Change iframe src with vbscript(open about language)

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, vbscript

So I'm trying to enable and disable livestream in an `iframe` `html` code, and need for it to check if the blank file `livestream.enable` is there to show livestream, and if it's not, it shouldn't display. And I've Googled and tried this on my own:

```
<iframe class="main" id="livestream" src="" width="320" height="180" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"> </iframe>

<script type="text/vbscript">       
    Function refreshGadget
    Set iFrame = document.getElementById("livestream")
    If iFrame.FileExists("livestream.enable") then
        iFrame.src = "http://my livestream URL here"
    Else
        iFrame.src = ""
    End If
    End Function

    window.setInterval(refreshGadget, 5000, VBScript)
</script>
```

Please help me correct this, I'm open to use `Javascript` or some other solution as well. But I only found one that is kinda similar to what I need but only in `vbscript`.

Source: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412344/vbscript-and-refreshing-an-iframe-with-a-file-exist-check)

Answer (score 0):

The example you are referencing uses `Scripting.FileSystemObject` fileExists to see if a file exists on the LOCAL file system.

There is no `FileExists` for an iFrame element (or any other DOM element.)

You simply can't do it the way you are trying.

If you have the URL to the stream, you might be able to do an Ajax call and see what the `http StatusCode` is, but the exact details would depend upon the streaming service.

Also, the code you have would stop and restart the steam every five seconds as you reset the `iFrame.src` value.

You also have a HTML error here:

```
<iframe class="main" id="livestream" src="" width="320" height="180" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"> /iframe>
```

Comment: Yes, it might check the LOCAL filesystem for the file, as the server runs on the same machine. I tried replacing livestream.enable with the whole path, but it still didn't work. Is there a better function to check the LOCAL filesystem though?

Also yes, it resets every 5 seconds in this code, because I was testing. Also it doesn't matter if it checks every 5 seconds, because the file will be there, so it won't change much, just refresh the page, right?

What HTML error were you referring to? I edited it also, because it needed a < to end the tag as well.

Answer (score 0):

So what about:

```html
<iframe class="main" id="livestream" src="" width="320" height="180" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                
<script type="text/vbscript">
Function refreshGadget
Option Explicit
DIM fso    
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set iFrame = document.getElementById("livestream")

If (fso.FileExists("C:\wamp64\www\livestream.enable")) Then
 iFrame.src = "http://URLhere"
Else
 iFrame.src = ""
End If
End Function
</script>
```

I still can't get ANY vbscripts to run at all, it seems. I've tried with Msgbox and WScript.Echo, I get nothing.. And the html file runs without any errors as I can see in Opera.

But how can I debug this, and find out what it does. Normally you can put in Msgbox, or alert(), but nothing shows up no matter :/